# I want to apply for a UK visa for my mother to meet her daughter

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, applications

I am planning to apply fir a UK visa for my mother from Saudi Arabia to meet her daughter and I will sponsor the whole trip. What documents are needed for her as she doesn’t work? She had a refusal of visa 5 years back due to inappropriate response from the family in the UK. Can this reason lead us to another refusal if we have the proper invitation letter from them?

Answer (score 2):

The visa officers will have the following main questions, and your documentation needs to answer these clearly:

1. Why should they believe she's travelling for the intended purpose?
2. Why should they believe she'll return back home, and not just abscond and remain illegally like so many others?

So any and every piece of documentation that could help answer these questions should be attached.

And finally you need to be honest with yourself: does your mother have a real reason to go back home? If not, **don't apply**, as a refusal will mean wasted money **and** a harder time getting a visa in the future.